# I have a long list of text in a column and want to paste it into one cell

Tags: text, transpose

Greetings to those much more gifted and knowledgeable than I,
I have a long list of text in a column and want to paste all of it into one cell, I tried =CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(B2:B19)) but I need to add a space in between each word. Where do I add, " "?

Comment: Are you using Excel?

Comment: I am using Sheets, I finally figured out textjoiner